# Cloudron Custom App (Couchbase) install fails: ECONNREFUSED

Tags: docker, containers, cloud, couchbase

I want to setup a custom app, Couchbase Server (a nosql database), on my cloudron server (followed this doc: https://docs.cloudron.io/packaging/tutorial/).
I used this Dockerfile:

```
FROM couchbase:community-7.2.0
COPY CloudronManifest.json /CloudronManifest.json
RUN ln -s /app/data /opt/couchbase/var //persistent data
EXPOSE 8091-8096 11210-11211
CMD ["couchbase-server"]  //start server
```

On my local machine building this docker image and running it is fine. I can reach the web UI on localhost:8091.

Installing the built image on my cloudron works until it is stuck in the "Starting" process.
The relevant errors are:

- Feb 10 13:43:11box:shell reload spawn: /usr/bin/sudo -S /home/yellowtent/box/src/scripts/restartservice.sh nginx
- Feb 10 13:43:11box:shell reload (stderr): sudo: unable to resolve host 1001629-690: Name or service not known
- Feb 10 13:23:00=> Healtheck error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.16.138:8091

Does anybody has an idea how to debug and solve this problem?
Many thanks!

**Detailed Description of my approach:**

```js
//CloudronManifest.json

{
  "id": "de.lfg.couchbaseserver",
  "title": "couchbase server",
  "author": "Dibbo-Mrinmoy Saha dibbomrinmoy@hotmail.com",
  "description": "database for the buecherteam",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "healthCheckPath": "/",
  "httpPort": 8091,
  "addons": {
    "localstorage": {} //enables write access to /app/data
  },
  "manifestVersion": 2
}
```

1. I have used two versions of the dockerfile above - the difference lies in `CMD ["couchbase-server"]` and `CMD ["/opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-server"]`
2. I execute these commands to install the app on cloudron:
3. `sudo docker build -t couchbase-server .`
4. `sudo docker tag couchbase-server dibbo/couchbase-server`
5. `sudo docker push dibbo/couchbase-server`
6. `cloudron install --image dibbo/couchbase-server`
7. For `CMD ["couchbase-server"]` the Couchbase server has to be started by myself, but very strangely in this version you have in the logs the following before I have started couchbase myself:

> Starting Couchbase Server -- Web UI available at http://:8091

Does this mean that couchbase has been started but then shut down?

8. Whereas for `CMD ["/opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-server"]` you don't have the log above, although couchbase server is running when checking with `/opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-server --status`
9. On both versions the ECONNREFUSED error appears and `netstat -tulpn` returns:

| Proto | Recv-Q | Send-Q | Local Address | Foreign Address | State | PID/Program name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tcp | 0 | 0 | 127.0.0.1:21200 | 0.0.0.0:* | LISTEN | 1/beam.smp |
| tcp | 0 | 0 | 0.0.0.0:4369 | 0.0.0.0:* | LISTEN | 20/epmd |
| tcp | 0 | 0 | 127.0.0.11:46071 | 0.0.0.0:* | LISTEN | - |
| tcp6 | 0 | 0 | :::4369 | :::* | LISTEN | 20/epmd |
| udp | 0 | 0 | 127.0.0.11:44475 | 0.0.0.0:* |  |  |

Only the epmd service of couchbase is running for some reason.

Thank you for your patience! Hope the extra information makes the problem clearer.

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with Cloudron, but I use Couchbase Server on Docker practically on a daily basis. Would you show more about how you created/started the image just on plain docker (e.g. `docker run ...`)? And maybe CloudronManifest.json might have some important details?

Comment: I added details to my questions. Hope they help.

Comment: > local machine building this docker image and running it is fine. I can reach the web UI on localhost:8091.

Ok, but localhost is only useful from that same host.  Hopefully it is also listening on of its ip addresses.
Looking at your CloudronManifest.json - what host is it supposed to use?

> unable to resolve host 1001629-690: Name or service not known

where does the hostname "1001629-690" come from? Maybe it should be the name of your couchbase server host?

>  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.16.138:8091
It's trying to connect to 172.18.16.138:8091, but nothing is listening